# Multiple users in a rails integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, testunit, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking how to do an integration for a flow that requires 2 users, in which you cannot JUMP around in the order.

```
User A does 1
User B does 2
User A does 3
User B does 4
User A does 5
...
```

Test code is executed in a random order therefor; I cannot write a series of tests such as: `test "user A does 1" do ... end` and expect them to execute in sequence

So, how should an integration test be written for the above situtation?

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyIntegrationTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

  test "Test interaction between 2 users" do 
    sign_in 'userA@mysite.com'
    assert_response :success

    get '/does/1'
    assert_response :success

    sign_out

    sign_in 'userB@mysite.com'
    assert_response :success

    get '/does/2'
    assert_response :success

    sign_out

    sign_in 'userA@mysite.com'
    assert_response :success

    get '/does/3'
    assert_response :success

    sign_out

    sign_in 'userB@mysite.com'
    # ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! .....
  end
```

Keep in mind, controller testing may be removed in Rails 5.

```
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950#issuecomment-77924771
```

Found this in rails issues:

```
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22742
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else coming here: For some reason the relevant helpers seem to not be documented in the current Rails guides, but I found this example from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/testing.html

```
require 'test_helper'



class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "login and browse site" do
    # User david logs in
    david = login(:david)
    # User guest logs in
    guest = login(:guest)
 
    # Both are now available in different sessions
    assert_equal 'Welcome david!', david.flash[:notice]
    assert_equal 'Welcome guest!', guest.flash[:notice]
 
    # User david can browse site
    david.browses_site
    # User guest can browse site as well
    guest.browses_site
 
    # Continue with other assertions
  end
 
  private
 
    module CustomDsl
      def browses_site
        get "/products/all"
        assert_response :success
        assert assigns(:products)
      end
    end
 
    def login(user)
      open_session do |sess|
        sess.extend(CustomDsl)
        u = users(user)
        sess.https!
        sess.post "/login", username: u.username, password: u.password
        assert_equal '/welcome', sess.path
        sess.https!(false)
      end
    end
end
```

This technique still seemed to work in a Rails 5.1 app.

Comment: this is also documented in the docs for the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` class
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code at this URL:

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing-examples
```

This is NOT present in the edgeguides as of Jan 10th, 2016.